# Transit visa at Incheon airport

Tags: transit-visas, south-korea, nigerian-citizens

I am a Nigerian and making a round trip for holiday from Lagos to East Timor, with a transit at Incheon airport, South Korea. Do i need a transit visa?

Answer (score 2):

You don’t need a visa if you transit within 24 hours and you hold valid documents for your next destination.

Per TIMATIC, the database used by airlines:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   Visa required, **except** for Passengers transiting through Seoul
>   (ICN) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third
>   country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international
>   transit area of the airport and have documents required for
>   the next destination.